# How to add a view programmatically after a controller has loaded

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a `ViewController` with a hidden view (let's call it, `boxInsideView`) on load. I'd like this `boxInsideView`'s controller, or `.swift` file, to fire whenever the user clicks the box, not when the view controller loads. Like if I would be making an `addSubview(boxInsideView` upon clicking the box.

[image]

Instantiating my `boxInsideView`

```
let cajasInsideView : CajaInsideView = {
        let cajasInside = CajaInsideView()
        cajasInside.delegate = self
        return cajasInside
    }()
```

On `viewDidLoad()` i have this code:

```
scrollView.addSubview(cajasInsideView)
        scrollView.addSubview(cajasView)
        scrollView.addSubview(collectionView)

        cajasView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cajasView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cajasView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        cajasView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true


        if !isClosed {
            cajasInsideView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            cajasInsideView.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: cajasView, withOffset: -10)
            cajasInsideView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
            cajasInsideView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cajasView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        scrollView.addConstraint(topConstraint!)

        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1000).isActive = true
        collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Once the `scrollView.addSubview(cajasInsideView)` is fired, automatically, my `.swift` file is triggered.

What i want to do is to add this View, also it's constraints and the animation uppon the click of that box.

My `openBox()` function:

```
@objc func openBox(){
        if isClosed {
            shareDropDown.dataSource = ["Añadir objetos a esta caja", "Añadir objeto nuevo a esta caja", "Sacar objeto de esta caja"]
            shareDropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
                if index == 1 {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Trastero", bundle: nil)
                    let uploadTrastero = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "UploadTrasteroViewController") as! UploadTrasteroViewController
                    uploadTrastero.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(uploadTrastero, animated: true)
                }
                if index == 0 {
                    self.setMoverObjeto()
                }
                print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
            }
            shareDropDown.width = 250
            scrollView.removeConstraint(topConstraint!)
            topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cajasInsideView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay:0, usingSpringWithDamping:0.7, initialSpringVelocity:0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.cajasInsideView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.cajasView.frame.height - 40, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: 360)
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.cajasView.frame.height + self.cajasInsideView.frame.height + 40), width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1000)
                self.scrollView.addConstraint(self.topConstraint!)
                self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.headerView.frame.height + self.cajasView.frame.height + self.cajasInsideView.frame.height + self.collectionView.frame.height)

                //self.collectionView.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: self.cajasInsideView)
            }, completion: { (completion) in
                self.isClosed = false
            })
        }
        else{
            shareDropDown.dataSource = ["Añadir objeto", "Editar", "Crear nueva caja", "Cambiar ubicación"]
            shareDropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
                if index == 0 {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Trastero", bundle: nil)
                    let uploadTrastero = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "UploadTrasteroViewController") as! UploadTrasteroViewController
                    uploadTrastero.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(uploadTrastero, animated: true)
                }
                if index == 1 {
                    self.setEditar()
                }
                if index == 2 {
                    self.openPopUpNewBox()
                }
                if index == 3{
                    let popupController = PopUpSetDirectionController()

                    popupController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
                    popupController.definesPresentationContext = true
                    popupController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext;
                    popupController.delegate = self
                    popupController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.4, alpha: 0)
                    self.present(popupController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
            }
            shareDropDown.width = 170
            scrollView.removeConstraint(topConstraint!)
            topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cajasView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            esMoverObjeto = false

            self.collectionView.reloadData()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay:0, usingSpringWithDamping:0.7, initialSpringVelocity:0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.cajasInsideView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.cajasView.frame.height - 40, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 0)
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.cajasView.frame.height), width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1000)
                self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.headerView.frame.height + self.cajasView.frame.height + self.cajasInsideView.frame.height + self.collectionView.frame.height)
                self.scrollView.addConstraint(self.topConstraint!)
            }, completion: { (completion) in
                self.isClosed = true
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can a user tap on a hidden view?

Comment: @rmaddy if you can check that gif i shared, you'll be able to see, what im talking about, there's 2 views, 1 hidden and another clickable as soon as the controller is fired.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your existing code look like?

Comment: @ZGski all i've done so far it's just add everything to view's subview on `viewDidLoad()`and all the animations that yo can see on the .gif

Comment: Could you include your code so we can understand the exact issue?

Comment: @ZGski added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your VC is loaded, you set the default for the 2nd `view.isHidden = true`. And If you tap the 1st view, you set the other `view.isHidden = false`.